# Regex Mandatory and Optional Groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to create a regex with groups which must be included in the string and groups which are only optional. I'm using c# for that.

My Target String looks like this

```
    ##my_first_string-2#E+1##
    ##my_second_string-2#E-2##
    ##my_third_string__##
```

I have the following **requirements**:

- *##* is mandatory at the beginning and the end (but this is not necessarily the beginning or end of line)
- the string between *##* and  *#*(or *##*) is mandatory as well
- E+{Numbers} or E-{Numbers} is optional

So far i have come up with

```
(##.*?##)
```

=> to match all Characters in between the 2 ## ##

```
(##)([A-Za-z\-])\w+(##)
```

=> to match the first string. But for some reason this captures *##my_first_string-2* and not only my_first_string-2

Could you help me create a regex for my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
##([^#]+?)(#E[+-][0-9]+)?##
```

The important part is:

```
(#E[+-][0-9]+)?
```

The "?" quantifier specifies zero or one occurrence

Replace the following with the character requirements for the string, currently its just "all except #"

```
([^#]+?)
```

Hope this helps.